# party post carrier

Tags: phrase-meaning

**At the post office**

---

**Man**: I'd like to send this letter to Italy and I was wondering what's the fastest way of sending it.

**Post Master**: The fastest way is **party post carrier** and the fee is 24 dollars and it's guaranteed service for 3 to 4 business days.

---

What does "**party post carrier**" mean?

Comment: Are you sure that’s what was said? Could it actually have been “a 3rd party post carrier”?

Comment: The exact text is found on Persian to English web sites. I agree it should be 'third party'.